# Html blocks get different widths with/without <br> inside

Tags: html, css

Block elements containing text get different widths depending on whether they contain a 
 tag or not. Why?

```
<div>
  <span>Mmm mmm mmmmmm</span>
</div>
```

is wider than

```
<div>
  <span>Mmm mmm<br>mmmmmm</span>
</div>
```

This behaviour is the same in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE (in their newest versions on Win7 OS).

(Text breaking, of course, varies with text size, side padding and number of characters in different words on each line.)

http://jsfiddle.net/olaim/q9BRT/1/

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question. 
I "solved" the problem by changing the span-display style to `dispaly:block;`  so both get to full 200px width. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/q9BRT/4/)

I think it's because "block" enforces a total block but inline-block bind it to the textflow, so the span resizes to it's content.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Works for you? ^^ Then you could possibly accept it as answer. ;)